# Why would "Cor-Ai" be earlier than "Singularity"?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

A while back my mum got the entire collection of *Stargate SG-1* from a garage sale; however I have been noticing that the episode order is off in comparison to what I see on [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118480/episodes?season=1&ref_=tt_eps_sn_1).

One example is on volume 4 of the set. *"Cor-Ai"* is episode 14 while *"Singularity"* is episode 15. but on both IMDb and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_SG-1_(season_1)%23Episodes) it's the other way around.

Now I did think that maybe this collection is bootleg but Volume 4 has a Featurettes section with 2 items. one is *"Profile on 'Captain Carter'"* while the other is *"Behind the scenes with the producers of SG-1"* not to mention that when the DVD starts there is a small MGM DVD animation.

To me, this seems to be much more extra work that some cheap bootleg ever has, particularly that each volume only has 5 episodes and bootlegs try and fit entire seasons on a single disk. (one example was a *Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha* collection I got from eBay; the 2 movies are on one disk and season 1 and 2 took an entire disk each).

So it's made me think that maybe these disks aren't bootleg but that doesn't explain the contradictory episode order. So I am wondering Why would "Cor-Ai" be earlier than "Singularity"?

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7XBT.jpg) is the Collectors Box the disk come in. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lac2.jpg) is what one of the disks look like and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NYt6.jpg) is how the disks are stored.

Also [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdCkh.png) is the DVD Menu of when your selecting which episode to play. Each one will take you to another menu where you can play the episode or select a scene.

Comment: Copies would still have the same order and content as the source, no?

Comment: Is it just the play order on the disk? Or is the order wrong on the printed list in/on the box? I've had other series (Farscape) have glitches in play order

Comment: @Richard I am currently on my iPad and the camera is crap. I'll be on my laptop tomorrow so I can post screenshots. however the box is sturdy and well made and the images on the disks don't look like crap high contrast copies. I'll be sure to take photos of them as well

Comment: @HorusKol it's actually on the disk in the menu, when you select the play episodes each item in the menu has *"Episode #"* followed by the title and they are ordered numerically by those titles. when I get on my PC tomorrow I'll post up screenshots of volume 4

Comment: @HorusKol - Yes, if they were ripped straight over, not if the individual episodes were ripped off the disk, then repackaged with a custom menu (which is easily done if you want to get more episodes onto one disk than were already on there).

Comment: There may well be a difference in the order of episodes on the official DVDs and the official online sources. Often a series of episodes is written or envisioned in a particular order; due to production constraints (budgeting, availability of talent, studio overrides, etc.), they are produced/aired in a different order. I don't know why the specific SG-1 episodes you cite are listed in different orders, but it is not uncommon. Babylon 5 has a number of episodes which were aired in a different order than the series creator intended, and the DVDs are in order by airdate.

Comment: hmm - my season boxset is an obvious repackaging of individual volumes (simpler production). The artwork on the disc is very different (though, that could be explained by a "collectors box" redux - but why is Mitchell on a season 1 disc?). More interestingly - there are 5 episodes on your disc, rather than the 4 I have on mine - and the menu is designed different. I think the use of plastic sleeves is a bit odd, too.

Comment: What's on the back of the box set?

Comment: A very good clue is that episode 14 of season 1 was *Hathor*, not *Cor-Ai*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's beginning to look like a highish-quality bootleg.

Other than these slightly odd things I noticed:

- Mitchell on a season 1 disc
- 5 episodes on the disc instead of 4
- Redesigned menu from original DVD releases
- Cheap sleeves

There's a big red flag in that the disc has an [ISRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Recording_Code) number printed on it - this is like an ISBN for audio recordings and music videos - and not for TV/movies recordings.

When I Google the number - CN-A60-05-0012-0 - the only match I can find is for a Metallica album on some dubious catalogue site.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. The fact that the disks have been repurposed is a dead giveaway

Comment: I'd have called BS on the fact that Mitchel is on the season 1 discs and not  O'Neill.